# How to get the last row based on some condition with group by column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
task_id     timestamp                           event_type
1           "2018-12-20 14:43:53.661153+01"     "open"
1           "2018-12-20 14:43:53.661153+01"     "interrupted"
1           "2018-12-20 14:43:53.661153+01"     "opened"
1           "2018-12-20 14:44:53.661153+01"     "closed"
2           "2018-12-20 14:43:53.661153+01"     "opened"
2           "2018-12-20 14:43:53.661153+01"     "interrupted"
2           "2018-12-20 14:43:53.661153+01"     "opened"
3           "2018-12-20 14:43:53.661153+01"     "opened"
3           "2018-12-20 14:45:53.661153+01"     "closed"
```

I need to get the data only for tasks where event_type is closed which is the last row for that task_id.
In above example I should get the data for task_id 1 and 3 but not for 2 as task 2 is not closed.
So for every task if the last row is closed then it should get the difference of time between last and second last row for that task.

```
task_id     time_diff_minutes
1           1
3           2
```

Comment: Can you post the code which you have tried already.

Comment: Can a task be reopened? Or is there always only a single `closed` per task and it's always the last row?

Answer (score 1):

We can aggregate by `task_id`, and then pivot out the opening and closing timestamps, should both exist.  If a task in fact has a closing timestamp, then we report it.

```
SELECT
    task_id,
    EXTRACT(epoch from MAX(CASE WHEN event_type = 'closed' THEN timestamp END) -
        MAX(CASE WHEN event_type <> 'closed' THEN timestamp END)) / 60 AS time_diff_minutes
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY task_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN event_type = 'closed' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: Ìt's easier to use `event_type <> 'closed'` instead of `='open'` to get the *second last row* and then `HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN event_type = 'closed' THEN timestamp END) > MAX(CASE WHEN event_type <> 'closed' THEN timestamp END)`

Comment: @dnoeth I'll go a step further and say that my answer, before the edit from your comment, was wrong.  I thought the OP just wanted total open time, but apprently not.

Comment: Well, then you have to modify the HAVING, too, there's `'open'` and `'opened'` :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize postgres LAG function. Check the SQL below :-

```
select test_id, extract(epoch from(event_time - prev_time))/60 as diff
from (select test_id,
LAG(event_time) over(partition by test_id) prev_time
,event_time
,event_type
from test
) a11
where event_type = 'closed'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/206d6/12)

Answer (score 0):

```
select task_id
   ,extract(epoch from(event_time - prev_time))/60 as diff
from 
 ( select task_id,
      row_number()     -- to filter the latest row
      over(partition by task_id
           order by event_time desc) as rn
     ,lead(event_time) -- second last row for that task
      over(partition by task_id
           order by event_time desc) as prev_time
     ,event_time
     ,event_type
   from test
 ) as dt
where rn = 1                -- last event
  and event_type = 'closed' -- must be closed
```